# Troubles debugging gRPC within a Quarkus app

Tags: java, grpc, quarkus

We're implementing a gRPC Client inside a Quarkus environment, however the request is not being completed.

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Resulted in: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:487)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.quarkus.grpc.runtime.supports.IOThreadClientInterceptor$1$1.lambda$onClose$3(IOThreadClientInterceptor.java:70)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:264)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:246)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$runOnContext$0(EventLoopContext.java:43)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    ... 4 more
```

We know that the message being built and the client configs are right because we can replicate it successfully using `grpcurl`.
**
We have also tried to use grpc env vars described in here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md. More specifically `GRPC_TRACE` and `GRPC_VERBOSITY`. But there were no changes in the output.

We also tried setting `quarkus.log.level=DEBUG` and `quarkus.log.category."grpc".level=DEBUG`

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Resulted in: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:487)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.quarkus.grpc.runtime.supports.IOThreadClientInterceptor$1$1.lambda$onClose$3(IOThreadClientInterceptor.java:70)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:264)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:246)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$runOnContext$0(EventLoopContext.java:43)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    ... 4 more

We know that the message being built and the client configs are right because we can replicate it successfully using grpcurl. We have also tried to use grpc env vars described in here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md. More specifically GRPC_TRACE and GRPC_VERBOSITY. But there were no changes in the output.We also tried setting quarkus.log.level=DEBUG and quarkus.log.category."grpc".level=DEBUG

022-11-08 10:08:42,074 FINE  [io.grp.net.Utils] (grpc-nio-worker-ELG-2-6) Using custom allocator: forceHeapBuffer=false, defaultPreferDirect=true
2022-11-08 10:08:42,087 DEBUG [io.grp.net.NettyClientHandler] (grpc-nio-worker-ELG-2-6) [id: 0x34d9ce18, L:/ - R:test.grpc.dev] OUTBOUND GO_AWAY: lastStreamId=2147483647 errorCode=2 length=70 bytes=466f6920666f72c3a761646f206f2063616e63656c616d656e746f20646520756d6120636f6e6578c3a36f206578697374656e74652070656c6f20686f737420...
2022-11-08 10:08:42,088 DEBUG [io.net.han.cod.htt.Http2ConnectionHandler] (grpc-nio-worker-ELG-2-6) [id: 0x34d9ce18, L:/ ! R:test.grpc.dev] Sending GOAWAY failed: lastStreamId '2147483647', errorCode '2', debugData 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'. Forcing shutdown of the connection.: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:130)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:430)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:931)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:354)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:895)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1372)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:742)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:728)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.onError(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:658)
    at io.grpc.netty.AbstractNettyHandler.exceptionCaught(AbstractNettyHandler.java:94)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.exceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireExceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:907)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.handleReadException(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:177)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2022-11-08 10:08:42,090 FINE  [io.grp.net.NettyClientHandler] (grpc-nio-worker-ELG-2-6) Network channel is closed
2022-11-08 10:08:42,119 DEBUG [io.grp.net.NettyClientHandler] (grpc-nio-worker-ELG-2-7) [id: 0x788c8189, L:/ - R:test.grpc.dev OUTBOUND SETTINGS: ack=false settings={ENABLE_PUSH=0, MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS=0, INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE=1048576, MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE=8192}
2022-11-08 10:08:42,119 DEBUG [io.grp.net.NettyClientHandler] (grpc-nio-worker-ELG-2-7) [id: 0x788c8189, L:/ - R:test.grpc.dev OUTBOUND WINDOW_UPDATE: streamId=0 windowSizeIncrement=983041
2022-11-08 10:08:42,139 FINE  [io.grp.net.NettyClientHandler] (grpc-nio-worker-ELG-2-7) Caught a connection error: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2022-11-08 10:08:42,140 FINE  [io.grp.net.Utils] (grpc-nio-worker-ELG-2-7) Using custom allocator: forceHeapBuffer=false, defaultPreferDirect=true
2022-11-08 10:08:42,140 DEBUG [io.grp.net.NettyClientHandler] (grpc-nio-worker-ELG-2-7) [id: 0x788c8189, L:/ - R:test.grpc.dev OUTBOUND GO_AWAY: lastStreamId=2147483647 errorCode=2 length=70 bytes=466f6920666f72c3a761646f206f2063616e63656c616d656e746f20646520756d6120636f6e6578c3a36f206578697374656e74652070656c6f20686f737420...
2022-11-08 10:08:42,141 DEBUG [io.net.han.cod.htt.Http2ConnectionHandler] (grpc-nio-worker-ELG-2-7) [id: 0x788c8189, L:/ ! R:test.grpc.dev Sending GOAWAY failed: lastStreamId '2147483647', errorCode '2', debugData 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'. Forcing shutdown of the connection.: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:130)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:430)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:931)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:354)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:895)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1372)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:742)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:728)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.onError(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:658)
    at io.grpc.netty.AbstractNettyHandler.exceptionCaught(AbstractNettyHandler.java:94)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.exceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireExceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:907)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.handleReadException(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:177)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2022-11-08 10:08:42,141 FINE  [io.grp.net.NettyClientHandler] (grpc-nio-worker-ELG-2-7) Network channel is closed
2022-11-08 10:08:42,161 DEBUG [io.grp.net.NettyClientHandler] (grpc-nio-worker-ELG-2-8) [id: 0x5f369dc9, L:/ - R:test.grpc.dev] OUTBOUND SETTINGS: ack=false settings={ENABLE_PUSH=0, MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS=0, INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE=1048576, MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE=8192}
2022-11-08 10:08:42,161 DEBUG [io.grp.net.NettyClientHandler] (grpc-nio-worker-ELG-2-8) [id: 0x5f369dc9, L:/ - R:test.grpc.dev] OUTBOUND WINDOW_UPDATE: streamId=0 windowSizeIncrement=983041
2022-11-08 10:08:42,182 FINE  [io.grp.net.NettyClientHandler] (grpc-nio-worker-ELG-2-8) Caught a connection error: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

What I would like to know is:

- Why gRPC environment variables are not taking effect?
- What can we do to get more insight on why the connection is being closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those environment variables work for the C-core library, not gRPC-Java (a separate repository, see https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java). gRPC-Java does all its logging via java.util.logging, so you can turn up the verbosity in the log config.